# Geometric Identities involving $π^2$

Tags: calculus, geometry, circles, exponentiation, pi

Are there any known geometric identities that have $π^2$ in the formula?

Comment: @Amzoti but what is the geometric identity? For example I already know Zeta(2)=$π^2$/6... But what geometrically proves that.

Comment: The area of a disk of radius $1$ is $\sqrt{\pi^2}$. With that, on a good day, I would get a great answer badge...

Comment: @julien ^Made me laugh! Hahah! :)

Answer (score 16):

Volume of a torus is $2 \pi^2 R^2 r$, where $r$ is the inner radius and $R$ is the outer radius.  Its surface area is $4 \pi^2 R r$.

Comment: Yes, I guess this one is more geometrical than the 4D thing because we can see tori more easily than those weird 4D-spheres :P

Comment: In the same vein the volume of the "football" we get by revolving the cycloid $x(t)=R(t-\sin t),$ $y(t)=R(1-\cos t)$ about the $x$-axis is (a single arc, so $0\le t\le 2\pi$)
$$V=5\pi^2R^3.$$

Answer (score 10):

The sphere of radius $r$ in $\mathbb R^4$ has volume (4-dimensional volume) $$ \frac{\pi^2 \; r^4}{2} $$ Here, we refer to the set $$ x_1^2 + x_2^2 + x_3^2 + x_4^2 \leq r^2.  $$

---

The sphere of radius $r$ in $\mathbb R^5$ has volume (5-dimensional volume) $$ \frac{8 \pi^2 \; r^5}{15} $$ Here, we refer to the set $$ x_1^2 + x_2^2 + x_3^2 + x_4^2+ x_5^2  \leq r^2.  $$

---

EDIT. My impression is that most students are not aware of the easy way to do volumes of the higher dimensional spheres. Let $V_m$ be the volume of the sphere of radius $1$ in $\mathbb R^m.$ So $$V_1=2, \; V_2 = \pi, \; V_3 = \frac{4 \pi}{3}.$$ In order to find $V_{m+2},$ we integrate $V_m R^m$ over the unit disc in the plane, where this radius $R= \sqrt {1 - x^2 - y^2}.$ Switching to polar coordinates, we get $$ V_{m+2} = \int_0^{2 \pi} \int_0^1 V_m (1-r^2)^{m/2} \, r \, dr \, d \theta = 2 \pi V_m \int_0^1  (1-r^2)^{m/2} \, r \, dr = \frac{2 \, \pi \, V_m}{m+2}. $$ So $$ V_4 =  \frac{2 \, \pi \, V_2}{4} = \frac{\pi^2}{2} $$ and $$ V_5 =  \frac{2 \, \pi \, V_3}{5} = \frac{2 \pi \cdot 4 \pi}{3 \cdot 5} = \frac{8\pi^2}{15}  $$

By induction,   $$  V_n = \frac{\pi^{n/2}}{(n/2)!},  $$ where in the case of odd $n$ we need to understand $$  (n/2)! = \Gamma \left( 1 + \frac{n}{2} \right)  $$ which is always a rational multiple of $\sqrt \pi$ (for odd $n$ it is).

Comment: Thanks! Quick question though... I recognize the double struck "R" as the "real number set", correct? But what does it mean when you superscript a 4? (Also, are we talking about a sphere or a hypersphere, or the hyper volume of a 3D sphere if that's even a thing?) Thanks! :)

Comment: @AlbertRenshaw : If $3D$ has only a geometric meaning for you, the 3-dimensional space is usually modeled as $\mathbb R^3 = \{ (x,y,z) \, | \, x,y,z \in \mathbb R \}$ in mathematics. If you're in $\mathbb R^4$, then you can consider that you need to look at 4-coordinate elements such as (w,x,y,z) for instance. You need to make sense of what '4-dimensional volume' means though. The best way to see it is to visualize an hypercube with sidelength $a$ size to have "4-dimensional volume" $a^4$, in a similar way than a cube with sidelength $a$ has volume $a^3$.

Comment: @AlbertRenshaw, he meant the set of points $(x,y,z,w)$ such that $x, y, z, w$ are all real numbers. When he means the sphere in $\mathbb{R}^4$, he meant the set $\{(x,y,z,w)\in\mathbb{R}^4:x^2+y^2+z^2+w^2=r^2\}$.

Comment: @AlbertRenshaw, not sure what to tell you, maybe these will help: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/N-sphere   ... http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euclidean_space

Comment: @PatrickDaSilva Thankyou for the explanation! So if I understand correctly, the first formula that was provided was for a 4-D hyper-sphere's hyper-volume? (Given that all coordinates in all 4 dimensions are part of the real number set?)

Comment: @PatrickDaSilva Or was he talking about a 3-D sphere's volume if it's is brought into a 4D world?

Comment: @WillJagy Got it! So just the hyper-volume of a 4-sphere! Thanks! :)

Comment: @Albert Renshaw : Yes ; in a similar way that a ball has "infinite area" (not on its boundary, but like, you can fit in infinitely many disks inside the ball since your disks will have volume zero), there are infinitely many 3d-balls that you can fit into a 4d-ball because 3d-balls have 4d-volume zero. So for the 4d-ball you need to consider the 4d-volume, it is the only notion of volume defined in this way that will make sense.

Comment: @PatrickDaSilva Very interesting! A 1d cube (line) has 2 vertices, a 2d cube (square) has 4 sides (4 1d cubes), a 3D cube has 6 faces (6 2d cubes), by that logic I would assumed a 4D cube has 8 cubes (8 3D cubes).
A 1D sphere (line) has 2 vertices, a 2D sphere (circle) has ∞ lines (1 face), a 3D sphere has ∞ faces (∞*∞ lines?), so a 4D sphere has ∞ spheres, $∞^2$ circles, and $∞^3$ lines? (And therefore ∞ area as well!)

Comment: Woooow here calm down. Infinite squared is infinite in your context. And you need to watch out when trying to extend integer valued sequences in the way you tried it. What you just did is a pure guess, I am not convinced at all it makes sense. 

But what I can say is that a $4D$-cube indeed has '8 $3D$-cubes' in this animation : http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CtSNStVW81M . I'll let you try figure out where they 'are'.